# How to install Vendetta Online?

Tags: games

I'm new to Ubuntu and I have downloaded a game called Vendetta Online , and it seems to have a .sh extension. When I double click it, it opens a text editor saying : can't open the file.   
What is the problem here and how do I fix this ? 
 
Is there a way to run a .sh in linux ?

I use HP notebook computer with amd64x processor and Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the file as executable to run it.

To do this, right click the file, click properties, and then click the permissions tab.
There, enable the executable bit.
[image]

Then all you have to do is double click the file, click run (when prompted), and follow what ever instructions the game has. You could also use run in terminal (if you are comfortable with the command line), as this could give useful output during the installation process, and the program may require it in any case.

Answer (score 8):

This game is available from the Software Centre under the `For Purchase` section.

Simply go to `Applications->Ubuntu Software Centre` and search `vendetta`.

[image]

From there you can click 'More Info' to get the page for this package. It is available to 'buy' (it is a subscription game I think) for $0.00 US.

[image]

Comment: Just so that it's mentioned: You don't need to set up a credit card or anything like that, you can just "buy" it if you have an Ubuntu single sign-on account.

Answer (score 3):

Files whose name end in **.sh** are shell scripts. Try to execute the file in your terminal if you have the appropriate access to it?

To start `Terminal` choose `Applications → Accessories → Terminal` or by pressing the key combination `ctrl + alt + t`.

You can type `chmod u+x filename.sh` to add execute access for the set `user` of the file in the terminal, and then type `filename.sh` to execute the file for you.

Comment: The terminal is opened using `ctrl + alt + t`. Using `sudo` is unnecessary and potenially harmful.

Comment: Thanks -- didn't know about the shortcut! I'll modify my answer.